# Scala Map[String,AnyRef] to Multiple Field RDD

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark

New to Scala (and Spark) and am using the Elasticsearch/Spark integration here -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html

I have an index in ES that I'm pulling into Spark (which works fine) using:

```
val rdd = sc.esRDD("blah/moreblah", "")
```

However, as per the documentation linked above I get (as expected) an RDD in the structure of Map[String,AnyRef]. The index in ES has 20+ fields in it, and I'd like to have each of these fields as separate "fields" in the RDD vs. a single string (sorry if I'm botching terminology).

Thanks for assistance in advance!

Comment: So when you say seperate fields what do you mean?

Comment: Hi Holden (reading your book btw) - so ultimately I'd like to work with this data using Spark SQL, which as I understand it means I need to apply a case class to my existing RDD (or extend Product if I'm over 22 fields) and then I can use it for Spark SQL operations.

Comment: Sorry, new to SO my edit time got cutoff...here's the whole reply:  Hi Holden (reading your book btw) - so ultimately I'd like to work with this data using Spark SQL (in 1.4.1), which as I understand it means I need to apply a case class to my existing RDD (or extend Product if I'm over 22 fields) and then I can use it for Spark SQL operations.  My roadblock is I can't seem to find good documentation for how to apply a case class to an esRDD. Hopefully that helps...